# Forcing outgoing traffic via specific IP by process or user

Tags: ubuntu, networking, iptables, routing, netplan

I have a network interface with 5 public IPs. These IPs are **working fine** for **incoming** traffic. What I need to do is "force" **outgoing** traffic through specific IPs.

I also made a simple REST endpoint if you make a request it'll tell you your IP in the response body. E.g curl, or fetch, or any other HTTP request method:

```
curl https://enosqoiqvbk6q22.m.pipedream.net
```

In the real scenario I will see HTTP requests (as well as a websocket though that matters less) to the same URLs from different processes. These I want to isolate by process (either putting each process under a diff system user, or any other mechanism for doing this on the process level).

This is how the netplan config looks:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
   id0:
      match:
        macaddress: aa:aa:cb:4b:04:74
      addresses:
        - 123.123.12.102/29
        - 123.123.12.103/29
        - 123.123.12.104/29
        - 123.123.12.105/29
        - 123.123.12.106/29
      gateway4: 123.123.12.101
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8,4.2.2.2]
```

`ip address` returns the following:

```
# ip address
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether aa:aa:cb:4b:04:74 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 123.123.12.102/29 brd 123.123.12.107 scope global eno1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 123.123.12.103/29 brd 123.123.12.107 scope global secondary eno1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 123.123.12.104/29 brd 123.123.12.107 scope global secondary eno1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 123.123.12.105/29 brd 123.123.12.107 scope global secondary eno1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 123.123.12.106/29 brd 123.123.12.107 scope global secondary eno1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::7a2b:cbff:fe4b:474/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eno2: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether aa:aa:cb:4b:04:75 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

If I had physical network interfaces per IP, I thought I could use ip namespaces via `ip netns` bound to each interface, and `ip netns exec ns_vlan02 ./someProcess`, but doesn't seem to be an option with only one interface.

I'm completely open to making a user per IP, or doing this on the process level. I'm essentially looking for any viable route with what I have.

I saw mentions of iptables, but it seems that assumes processA or userA will always send requests to a different domain/ip than processB or userB. In my scenario requests are going to the same domain/ip (like that pipedream URL at the beginning).

Edit - discoveries so far:

## Option 1 - per user iptables

https://serverfault.com/a/236724/621956

DNS was broken, but seems to work after specifying interface when setting up the rule!

`-o en1`

## Option 2 - use containers (lxd/docker)

Might expose other control over how networking behaves for processes within, though the concern is that just introduces unnecessary complexity. Option 1 preferred if dns issue is resolved.

## Other options?

How could I approach this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You may want to have a look at iptables-extensions(8):

> ```
> iptables [-m name [module-options...]]  [-j target-name [target-options...]
>
> ...
>
> owner
>    This  module  attempts to match various characteristics of the packet
>    creator, for locally generated packets. This match is only valid in the
>    OUTPUT and POSTROUTING chains. Forwarded packets do not have any socket
>    associated with them. Packets from kernel threads do have a socket, but
>    usually no owner.
>
>    [!] --uid-owner username
>
>    [!] --uid-owner userid[-userid]
>           Matches if the packet socket's file structure (if it has one) is
>           owned by the given user. You may also specify a numerical UID,
>           or an UID range.
>
>    [!] --gid-owner groupname
>
>    [!] --gid-owner groupid[-groupid]
>           Matches if the packet socket's file structure is owned by the
>           given group.  You may also specify a numerical GID, or a GID
>           range.
>
>    [!] --socket-exists
>           Matches if the packet is associated with a socket.
> ```

**Edit:** Sorry I just saw that this was your option 1.